# Xfce — middle-click lowers window: where is that Xfwm4 setting?

Tags: xfce, mouse, window-management, xfwm4

In KDE I have noticed the Kwin capability of editable mouse actions on the window frame, including the middle-click (I used it for "close"), which is normally missing in other window managers. In Gnome/Matacity related desktops (Mate, Pantheon, Budgie, Cinnamon), middle and right-click can be used and [edited](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/15378/18449) with `dconf` (`gsetings` — excepting for "close"), but not in Xfwm4. (Answers like those under [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/202874/925128) are applying to metacity I guess. Even so, my gsettings for `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar` is 'none'.)

I wonder if there are similar settings for Xfce with Xfwm. I have noticed that ***middle-click on the window top frame switches between non-minimized windows.***

(The behavior is the same as `lower` for `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar` with metacity.)

**Where is that setting in Xfce with Xfwm4?**

Is it editable? Are there other similar mouse-on-window-frame actions available in Xfce with Xfwm4?

---

In Window Manager (`xfwm4-settings`), the only mouse setting is the "double click to maximize"

[image]

The same in Settings Editor (`xfce4-settings-editor`) under Xfwm4 (nothing about a "middle-click' to 'lower' etc).

[image]

In Window Manager Tweaks (`xfwm4-tweaks-settings`) there is just a setting for the mouse wheel (under Accessibility for rolling up the window, under Workspaces for switching them.

[image].

[image]

I cannot find anything else that could trigger the action I'm describing.

Comment: Have you checked inside `xfce4-settings-manager`?

Comment: @Ned64 - yes. I will clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That setting is absent in Xfwm4, the default Xfce window manager. The option cannot be enabled with Xfwm4 unless the program itself is modified. The way to go is to use a different window manager or to post a [feature request](https://wiki.xfce.org/wish_list).

On the other hand, left-clicking the panel window button (with Window Buttons item) already minimizes the window anyway, while middle click (optionally) closes it, so there is little need for that feature as long as a panel is used.

[image]